# Buffer solution calculation using pka

Tags: physical-chemistry

> A solution is obtained when $\pu{10.0 cm3}$ of $\pu{0.100 moldm−3}$ sodium hydroxide is added to $\pu{20.0 cm3}$ of $\pu{0.100 mol dm−3}$ ethanoic acid ($\ce{\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}}$ = 4.76). Find its $\mathrm{pH}$.

I got $\mathrm{pH} = 4.76$, but the answer key is $4.46$. I think the answer is wrong. What do you guys think?

Here is how I solve it:

mole of $\ce{OH-} = 0.1*10*10^{-3} = 10^{-3}$ moles

mole of Acid =$\mathrm{ 0.1*20*10^{-3} = 2*10^{-3}}$moles

$$\ce{Acid + OH- -> Base + Water}$$

Start    $\mathrm{ 2*10^{-3}}$ ,   $\mathrm{10^{-3}}$ ,      $\mathrm{ 0}$

Change   $\mathrm{ -10^{-3}}$ , $\mathrm{-10^{-3}}$ , $\mathrm{10^{-3}}$

End     $\mathrm{10^{-3}}$    ,  $\mathrm{0}$  ,  $\mathrm{10^{-3}}$

$\ce{[Acid] = \frac{mole}{volume} = \frac{10^{-3}}{30*10^{-3}}}$

$\ce{[Base] = \frac{mole}{volume} = \frac{10^{-3}}{30*10^{-3}}}$

$$\mathrm{pH = pKa + log \frac{[Base]}{[acid]}}$$

$$\mathrm{  = 4.76 + log \frac{1}{1} }$$

$$\mathrm{= 4.76}$$

Answer (score 0):

1. $K_a = 10^{-pK_a} = 10^{-4.76}$ = 1.74x10<sup>-5</sup> mol dm<sup>-3</sup>
2. Initial moles $\ce{CH3COOH}$ = 2x10<sup>-3</sup> mol and  initial moles $\ce{NaOH}$ = 1x10<sup>-3</sup> mol
3. $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is in excess $\therefore$ final moles $\ce{CH3COOH}$ = 1x10<sup>-3</sup> mol, final moles $\ce{CH3COONa}$ = 1x10<sup>-3</sup> mol
4. New volume = 0.03 dm<sup>3</sup> $\therefore$

   - $\ce{[CH3COOH]}$ = $\frac {1x10^{-3}} {0.03}$ = 0.0333 mol dm<sup>-3</sup>
   - $\ce{[CH3COONa]}$ = 0.0333 mol dm<sup>-3</sup>
5. $K_a = \frac {\ce{[H+]} {\ce{[CH3COO^{-}]}}} {\ce{[CH3COOH]}} \therefore \ce{[H+]} = \frac{{K_a} {\ce{[CH3COOH]}}} {\ce{[CH3COO-]}} = \frac{{1.74x10^{-5}} * {0.333}} {0.333}$ = 1.74x10<sup>-5</sup> mol dm<sup>-3</sup>
6. $pH = -log([H^{+}]) = -log(1.74x10^{-5})$ = 4.76

---

I would imagine that the answer is merely a typo, unless we're both making mistakes.

Comment: The final volume is 30 ml as the question states that 10 ml is added to 20 ml, so the concentrations of acid and base are not the same but in the ratio 2/3 to 1/3 of 0.1 mol /dm$^3$ and this produces pH= 4.46. The calculation given only works when the acid /base concentrations are large compared to $\ce{H^+}$ and the equilibrium $K_w=\ce{[H+][OH-]}$ can be ignored.

Comment: @porphyrin Hi mate, what you said sounds logical. However, I get taught that a concentration of base and a new concentration of acid must be calculated from the new volume, using the final moles. This makes me unsure.

Comment: I agree that a $2:1$ proportion gives the answer, but I don't see why though. The answer proposed calculates final concentrations of acid and base (i.e. it takes into consideration volume change). The amount of moles of base added is half the amount of moles of initial acid, so final moles (thus concentration because they're in the same vessel) will be the same.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned in the old post, the concentration of acid and base is a thousand fold the concentration of protons, which I think should be close enough to ignore water dissociation.

Comment: @ralk912 It's making me wonder whether the answer doesn't take into consideration new concentrations, due to new moles and a new volume. I wouldn't imagine that the initial moles and concentrations will remain the same even after a reaction.

Comment: If that's the case, I would argue the answer is wrong. This is a typical titration of a weak acid with a weak base, and this is the half equivalence point, which corresponds to the $\text{p}K_\text{a}$ of the acid. Exceptions are, of course, deviations of Henderson-Hasselbach's equation, as mentioned by @porphyrin (more here: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed078p1499)

Comment: It is the concentrations initially present that mater not the number of moles. The total amount of acid is $c_a=\ce{[AH] + [H+] - [OH-]} $ and base $c_b=\ce{[B]  - [H+]  +[OH-]} $ where $c_a$ and $c_b$ are the initial amounts and $\ce{[AH], \,[B]}$ the equilibrium amounts that you put to the equation for $K_A=\ce{[H+][B]/[AH]}$. As the initial concentrations are so large vs $\ce{[H+]}$ or $K_w/\ce{[H+]}$ these can be ignored giving  $\ce{[H+]}=K_Ac_a/c_b$

Comment: You do the reaction and end up with a new volume and new moles, so new concentrations have to be calculated. The initial moles/concentrations/volumes can't be used. The 20cm3 of acid and 10cm3 of base are now together at 30cm3. The acid and base have reacted to give new moles of each, so this means new concentrations.

Comment: I agree with @KianStevens on this one, the concentrations involved in the $K_\text{a}$ expression are AFTER equilibrium is stablished, not before.